# Is the closure of a Hausdorff space, Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

$(X,\mathcal T)$ is a topological space which has a dense Hausdorff subspace. Is $X$ Hausdorff?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For a generalisation, one can easily show that *every* Hausdorff space can be embedded as a dense subset of a non-Hausdorff space.  Given a Hausdorff space $X$, define a new space $Y = X \cup \{ \alpha , \omega \}$ so that the open sets are just the open sets of $X$ together with the whole space $Y$.  Then $X$ is clearly a dense subspace of $Y$ (the only neighbourhood of either $\alpha$ or $\omega$ is the entire space $Y$), and $Y$ is not Hausdorff (actually, it is not even T$_0$, since $\alpha$ and $\omega$ have exactly the same open neighbourhoods).

Answer (score 22):

No.

Consider $\Bbb R$ with the trivial topology $\{0\}$ is a dense subset, it is certainly Hausdorff, but space itself is certainly not.

Comment: It is even a completely uniformizable non-Hausdorff space! :)

Answer (score 13):

For a slightly less trivial example, consider $X = [0,1] \cup \{1'\}$, where $1'$ is an "extra copy of $1$" so that basic neighbourhoods of $1'$ are $\{1'\} \cup (1-\epsilon,1)$
for any $\epsilon > 0$.  On $[0,1]$, the usual topology is taken.  Then $[0,1]$ is 
a dense subspace which is Hausdorff, but $X$ is not Hausdorff because $1$ and $1'$ don't have disjoint neighbourhoods.

Answer (score 12):

Algebraic geometers will smile and think of the generic point of their favourite irreducible scheme...

[For non algebraic geometers: a scheme is the basic object studied in algebraic geometry.
It has an underlying topological space which is almost never Hausdorff.
 Very often however a scheme $X$  has a so-called *generic point* $\eta\in X$, such that the singleton set $\{\eta\}$, obviously a Hausdorff subspace, is dense in $X$. The scheme $X$ is then called irreducible.
I am answering the question in order to show that the situation arises in real (mathematical) life, contrary to what some (excellent) other  answers might suggest.]

Comment: The trivial topology arises more often than one thinks! It's one of my favorite sources for counterexamples! :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is the closure of its non-closed point.